# Hook/Clasp/Latch? (For a necklace)

Tags: word-usage

When someone fastens a "clasp bracelet/necklace", will it be natural to use:

> **She clasped her necklace/bracelet**. (I feel this sounds okay)
>
> **She latched her necklace/bracelet.** (Maybe this sounds a bit off.)
>
> **She hooked her necklace/bracelet.** (Maybe this sounds a bit off too)

Or will it only be: **"She fastened her necklace/bracelet."**

And when we wear our necklace, sometimes, the clasp starts showing and we have to turn the necklace around. What will be a natural way to express that?

> The **clasp/hook/latch** of your necklace is showing.

Is there a better way to describe it? What sounds the best "clasp" or "hook" or "latch"? I feel that "clasp" sounds the best?

Comment: latches are for doors, gates and boxes, etc. not necklaces. And careful, clasp something or someone means to hold. You do not clasp a necklace. You clasp your dog  or child or loved one. That said, necklaces have clasps.

Comment: You fasten a necklace. No need to refer to the clasp.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that all three of those sentences can be naturally used to describe something done with the necklace or bracelet as a whole rather than the mechanism itself.

For instance:

> She clasped her necklace *to her chest*.
>   She latched her necklace *onto her workbench*.
>   She hooked her bracelet *on a piece of thread.*

---

In order to make it clear that it's the mechanism itself that's being discussed, you need to use an article and preposition:

> She closed **the** clasp **of** her necklace.
>   She fastened **the** latch **of** her bracelet.

---

I don't know what it means to say that the (clasp / hook / latch) is *showing*. That's not something that's normally hidden—or at least not specifically hidden.

If you mean you see that it's come undone, and that the jewellery is at risk of falling off, you might just say:

> The clasp of your necklace is **undone**.
>   The hook of your bracelet is **loose**.
>   The latch of your necklace is **open**.

Any of them will do, but it's the *showing* part in the original that is a little strange.

Comment: It's like when the necklace turns around in a way that that the clasp is in the front. Thus, you fix it by turing it around again. This will "showing" work in that case. (Because normally you don't see it because it gets covers by our hair.)

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish In that situation, nobody would normally refer to the clasp. They would simply say that the necklace or bracelet has *turned around* or is now *backwards*. While seeing the clasp would be an indicator of that, it's not something that would be referred to specifically. (But note that many necklaces and bracelets have mechanisms keeping them in place that can be visible no matter what the rotation of the jewellery is.)

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple, even for creative writing:

> She fastened her necklace.

or:

> She fastened her necklace, even though the clasp was broken.

Note that *clasp* can also mean *hold*, so *she clasped her necklace* can convey an unintended meaning.